# How to trick Chrome's native async/await to play along angularjs (1.x)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, async-await, v8

For quite a while I've been able to successfully use async/await syntax with Babel transpilation and an AngularJS (1.x) framework. The common problem is that async/await uses native Promises as opposed to angular's `$q` so async stuff runs outside of the digest loop.

I hacked this by doing the following:

```
angular.module('app', []).run(($window, $q) => {
     $window.Promise = $q;
});
```

I know that this is dangerous for a multitude of reasons but works like a charm without any wrappers like `$async` library that is not a drop-in solution (and I want a drop-in solution).

Anyway it works great until I transpile the source code that generates JS that calls the actual `Promise` constructors etc. But this is a nightmare for debugging as even with source-maps the Chrome debugger often gets lost. But Chrome supports async/await for a while now and debugging those statements works perfectly. But when I edit my babel config not to transpile async/awaits then my `window.Promise` stops working because V8 must use it's internal Promise constructor when executing those async/await statements.

Question is - is there a way to hack it to make it work with my current setup? I'm willing to dig into V8, compile my own chromium etc. Because after all I will still be transpiling async/awaits when making production builds - I just need it to work natively in local environment for debugging purposes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: I wrote a babel plugin that transpiles this to wrap in $q.when

Comment: That sounds good.  Do you have it public?

Comment: https://github.com/kamilkp/babel-plugin-transform-angular-async